# Java getting stdOut from an external process - Getting intermittent results

Tags: java, process, stdout

I'm having a problem with getting output from a process when using the `ProcessBuilder` in Java.  My application is a GUI application where I allow the user to add user entries into a file which contain user credentials. The passwords are encrypted in the file. The GUI application has an "Add user" and a "Change Password" button.  When either of those buttons are pressed, the below function is executed which executes an external program to encrypt the password.  This seems to work on Solaris and Windows OK, but I'm having problems running this on Linux (OEL 6.x, Java 1.7).  For Linux, the "Add User" functionality works in which the password becomes encrypted, but the "Change Password" is unable to execute the external program correctly.

I've read other answers on here, and I have my input and error streams consumed in a thread.

Based on some debug output, I can see the order in which the threads and the process exit seem to dictate as to how I get output from the process.

```
private boolean getObfuscatedPassword(String passAsPlainText, StringBuilder obfPass)
{
        //Check path of binary
        File cmdBin = new File(txtPath.getText());
        boolean retVal = true;

        if (passAsPlainText.length() == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "The given password is empty", 
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }
        if (!cmdBin.exists())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "The binary does not exist in the specified path.  Choose a different binary location.", 
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }


        //execute command with options
        try{
            String strCmd = new String(txtPath.getText() + " -encryptPW " + passAsPlainText );
            String [] strCmds = {txtPath.getText(), "-encryptPW", passAsPlainText};

            //Debug
            for (int i =0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(strCmds[i]);
            }

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(strCmds);
            //pb.inheritIO();

            Process cmdProc = pb.start();

            StringBuilder strBOut = new StringBuilder();

            LogStreamReader lsrOut = new LogStreamReader(cmdProc.getInputStream(), strBOut);
            BufferedReader bfOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmdProc.getInputStream()));
            Thread td1 = new Thread(lsrOut, "LogStream1");
            td1.start();
            td1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

            StringBuilder strBErr = new StringBuilder();    
            LogStreamReader lsrErr = new LogStreamReader(cmdProc.getErrorStream(), strBErr);
            Thread td2 = new Thread(lsrErr, "LogStream2");
            td2.start();

            /*  This was an attempt to move the LogStreamReader to the main thread of execution, to see if it works differently than the threaded version.
            try {
                String line;

                while ((line = bfOut.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    strBOut.append(line);
                }

                System.out.println("reached thread null main");

                bfOut.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            */

            cmdProc.waitFor();
            System.out.println(cmdProc.exitValue());

            td1.join();
            td2.join();

            if (strBErr.length() > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(strBErr.toString());

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        "(Err1) Unable to encrypt the password.  The executable version or path may be incorrect" ,
                        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                retVal = false;

            }
            else if (strBOut.length() == 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        "(Err2) Unable to encrypt the password.  The executable version or path may be incorrect" ,
                        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                retVal = false;
            }
            else
            {                   
                obfPass.append(strBOut.toString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString(),  "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            retVal = false;
        }
        return retVal;
}
```

and the `LogStreamReader` is based on the `StreamGobbler` I've seen in other Java posts here:

```
public class LogStreamReader implements Runnable {

    private BufferedReader reader;
    private StringBuilder strBldr;
    private InputStreamReader isr;

    public LogStreamReader(InputStream is, StringBuilder strb){
        this.isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        this.strBldr = strb;
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                strBldr.append(line);
            }

            System.out.println("reached thread null");

            reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Results

```
/home/XXXXX/x86_64_Linux_6X.64/gnu444-g-tp/bin/tool
-encryptPW
ss
F4aru5cF95Lde5k507i3D7VRK7aru5cF95Lde5k507i3mVIZkJeD5DeMV2nBOPU1BxUon8NZkJeD5DeMV2nBOPU1BNk
reached thread null
reached thread null main
0
-------------------------end of add user
/home/XXXXXXX/x86_64_Linux_6X.64/gnu444-g-tp/bin/tool
-encryptPW
ss
DqOZEtQ93tnHotIB-rGvxrhjUrOZEtQ93tnHotIB-rGvxqnzGjU3t3UmfCNXcdeFX9eKNwnzGjU3t3UmfCNXcdeFXTk
reached thread null
reached thread null main
0
-----------------------end of add user

-------------------start "change password" button
/home/XXXXX/x86_64_Linux_6X.64/gnu444-g-tp/bin/tool
-encryptPW
dddd
reached thread null main            <-- thread or main is exiting before process
0
reached thread null
-------------------end of "change Password"
-------------------start of "change password again"
/home/XXXXX/x86_64_Linux_6X.64/gnu444-g-tp/bin/tool
-encryptPW
test
reached thread null main                <-- seem to be exiting before
0
reached thread null
```

When I have the threads (no readLine in main thread):

```
------"Add user"
/home/XXXXX/x86_64_Linux_6X.64/gnu444-g-tp/bin/tool
-encryptPW
aa
0
36Iz05GxD5hlK5OXu7Q_97nJe7Iz05GxD5hlK5OXu7Q_ONg5iRKx7vKST-TrQHo_zFoep0h5iRKx7vKST-TrQHo_zVc
reached thread null
reached thread null
------------start "Change Password"
/home/XXXXX/x86_64_Linux_6X.64/gnu444-g-tp/bin/tool
-encryptPW
ffff
0
reached thread null
reached thread null
-----------start "Change Password"
/home/XXXXXX/x86_64_Linux_6X.64/gnu444-g-tp/bin/tool
-encryptPW
sssaa
0
reached thread null
reached thread null
```

SO, I'm wondering if my buffered readers are exiting too early or the process is exiting prior to the readers reading the stream. I don't understand why clicking on "Add user" seems to work whereas clicking on "Change password" button does not work, yet both use the same function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum running example (with less domain specific stuff)?

Comment: Not sure that I can since you'll need the outside running program.  I could try to see if I can simplify the GUI and provide something, but it won't be until tomorrow.

Comment: I seem to definitely experience this problem with Java 1.7.0_09-icedTea version.  I get intermittent issues with Java 1.7 and above.  I'll try to use inheritIO for Java 7 and above, and see if I get more consistent results.